# Javascript comparing alphanumeric strings

Tags: javascript, string

I have a collection of around 100 strings which have the following format and iterate up.

```
aa-000-1
aa-000-7-8
aa-000-20-10
```

I'm attempting to do a comparison on these strings in order to categorise them based on information i'm provided with (I'm simply printing out the associated category at the moment). I would do this by feeding them into a function one at a time.

Some categories are straight forward for example:

```
Category A:
aa-000-8
aa-000-8-1
aa-000-8-2
aa-000-8-3
aa-000-8-5

Category B:
aa-000-8-4
```

For which I wrote the following code:

```
  var category_guid = 'aa-000-8-3';
  if(category_guid.charAt(7) === '8') {
    if(category_guid.charAt(9) === '4' ) {
      console.log('Category B');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Category A');
    }
  }
```

However some categories have a mixture of numbers, for example:

```
Category C:
aa-000-2
aa-000-4-3
aa-000-9-4
aa-000-10-2
aa-000-10-3
aa-000-11-4
aa-000-13-1
aa-000-13-5
```

If I continued with my current code, this would end up being hundreds of lines of codes of if-else statements, surely there is a better way to compare?
What would be the most efficient way of checking each string and printing it's associated category?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough data to solve this problem. What are the possible categories, and how do you put the string in a particular category?
 Please mention all the cases.

Comment: I'd read this as "how do I get an alphabetical sort with numerical subsort ", so that "a-9" comes before "a-10"

Comment: "*in order to categorise them based on information i'm provided with*" - how is that information provided in the first place? Your code should have the same structure.

Comment: At the moment i'm only trying to print out the associated category rather than putting the string in a category. I have created a spreadsheet that has all of the strings and their associated categories [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vROKFjeELpxKppvlEEfnsyiMC0ruk3CAMUunxzrwPgKVH5qJaKuQsfXneRtQOLDpxCSyTEh-dDex_6R/pubhtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.split()` method on the categories. For example, `'aa-000-8-1'.split('-')`returns the array `['aa', '000', '8', '1']`. From there, you can access each number easily and cleanly.

You can read more about the `.split()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).